# Invalid write in realloc call

Tags: c, valgrind, realloc

I'm having some trouble with this code snippet.

```
size_t* defines = malloc(sizeof *defines);
if (!defines)
    exit(1);

size_t def_cap = 1;
size_t def_size = 0;

...

for(condition) {
    ...

    if (def_size == def_cap) {
        void* tmp = realloc(defines, def_cap*=2);
        if(!tmp)
            exit(1);
        defines = tmp;
    }
    defines[def_size++] = foo;
}
```

I'm getting a "malloc.c:2842: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (_rtld_global_ro._dl_pagesize - 1)) == 0' failed." error when I run. Valgrind tells me there's an invalid write of size 8 in the realloc call. What's going on? condition and foo are part of a mess of file parsing that doesn't use or modify any of the variables above.

Comment: Do you change (increment, for example) `defines` somewhere?

Comment: It appears that you have corrupted the heap data structures by overwriting some data ranges outside the allocated area. This could have happened due to an out of bound access. The code that is in the `...` is essential to figure that out.

Comment: @tkausl Control F says no.

Comment: Like `malloc`, `realloc` requires a size in bytes: `realloc(defines, def_cap * sizeof(*defines));`

Comment: `realloc(defines, def_cap*=2);` - not a problem as such with the `*=`, but it looks like a really bad style of wanting to do too much in one line.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks, that worked. I'm an idiot.

Comment: Oh, you're probably not. Most of us have been there and felt like one, though, I guess. (And you should accept Ryan's CW answer, so that the case is officially closed.)

Comment: Just as soon as SO's 15min delay allows me to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realloc` takes a number of bytes just like `malloc`, so you need to multiply the number of entries by `sizeof(size_t)` as before:

```
def_cap *= 2;
void* tmp = realloc(defines, def_cap * sizeof *defines);
```